# how to put an object of your own class in the Predicate delegate

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates, predicate

I am making a data processing class, the return from the getData method of which is carried out on the basis of the function passed to it using the delegate Predicate.The getData method is planned to be used by other classes as well, so I used the generic
But I can't put an object of my own class in the delegate parameter

I wanted to pass the generalization  to the delegate, but I don't know how to do it. I've also tried putting my class directly into a function, but that doesn't help either.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result1 = new MyDataProcessing().GetData<MyFile>("C:\\",MyFunc);
        var result2 = new MyDataProcessing().GetData<MyFile>("C:\\", MyFunc2);
    }  
    static bool MyFunc(MyFile file)=>file.FileInfo.Name.Contains("A");
    static bool MyFunc2(MyFile file) => file.FileInfo.Length>1000;
}
interface MyData
{
}
public class MyFile:MyData
{
    public MyFile(string name)
    {
        FileInfo = new FileInfo(name);
    }
   public FileInfo FileInfo { get; }
}

public  class MyDataProcessing 
{
    public List<T> GetData<T>(string path,Predicate<T>? filter = null)
    {
        List<T> list = new();
        IEnumerable<string> files;
        if (filter != null && typeof(T).Name is MyFile)
        {
            files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Where(x => filter(new MyFile(x)));
            foreach (var file in files)
                list.Add(new MyFile(file));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Thanks! I took your comments into consideration and that's what happened, are there any comments on this code?**

```
    public class Program
{
    public bool MyFunc(IMyData data)
    {
        if (data is MyFile myfile)
        {
            return myfile.FileInfo.Name.Contains("A");
        }

        return false;
    }
    public bool MyFunc2(IMyData data)
    {
        if (data is MyFile myfile)
        {
            return myfile.FileInfo.Length > 1000;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Program();
        var result1 = new MyDataProcessing().GetData("C:\\", p.MyFunc);
        var result2 = new MyDataProcessing().GetData("C:\\", p.MyFunc2);
    }


    public interface IMyData { }

    public class MyFile : IMyData
    {
        public MyFile(string name)
        {
            FileInfo = new FileInfo(name);
        }
        public FileInfo FileInfo { get; }
    }

    public class MyDataProcessing
    {
        public List<IMyData> GetData(string path, Predicate<IMyData>? filter = null)
        {
            List<IMyData> list = new();
            IEnumerable<string> files;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Where(x => filter(new MyFile(x)));
                foreach (var file in files)
                    list.Add(new MyFile(file));
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear to me why you've made `GetData` a generic method if it's only actually useful for `MyFile`.

Comment: Because I want to pass other classes to this method in the future

Comment: `MyFunc` and `MyFunc2` should be `Predicate<MyFile>`. Then, it becomes `static Predicate<MyFile> MyFunc = file => file.FileInfo.Name.Contains("A");`.

Comment: So would you intend to add code to `GetData<T>` for each type? It really doesn't sound like a generic method is the right design here - because you don't have *generic* logic.

Comment: I plan to submit types that implement a certain common interface MyData

Comment: Then maybe your method should just be `public List<MyData> GetData(string path, Predicate<MyData> filter)`? Fundamentally it's hard to suggest anything concrete with such shifting sands... but a generic method which has to check the type argument and behave differently is always a design smell.

Comment: `typeof(T).Name is MyFile` makes no sense because `typeof(T).Name` is a `string`. Either `typeof(T) is typeof(MyFile)` or `T is MyFile` where the second approach also allows descendants of `MyFile`. But these type tests defy the purpose of generics.

Comment: Your processing class does not add much value to processing the data directly with LINQ. You get `FileInfo`s and `DirectoryInfo`s directly with `var files = new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles().Where(f => f.Length > 1000).ToList();` and `var directories = new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateDirectories().Where(d => d.Name.Contains('A', StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();`.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes The solution of the functions Func1 and Func2 are demonstrative in nature and in a real task will contain more complex logic and change from the client's side. I want to keep this class unchanged and extensible to external requests. I'm trying to implement the Open/Closed (SOLID) principle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the new [Static abstract members in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces) feature:

```cs
public interface MyData<T>
{
    T Data { get; }
    static abstract IEnumerable<T> EnumerateData(string path);
    static abstract MyData<T> Create(T info);
}
```

The interface contains a static method for enumerating the data and one for the creation of a MyData object with one parameter. This is useful since we cannot declare constructors in the interface.

The idea is to delegate the decision of how to enumerate the input data and how to create a data class to the data class itself as static methods and remove it from the data processing class.

An example implementation is:

```cs
public class MyFile : MyData<FileInfo>
{
    public MyFile(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        Data = fileInfo;
    }

    public FileInfo Data { get; }

    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> EnumerateData(string path)
        => new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles();

    public static MyData<FileInfo> Create(FileInfo info) => new MyFile(info);
}
```

We can declare a data processing class like this (note that I made the method static):

```cs
public class MyDataProcessing
{
    public static List<U> GetData<T, U>(string path, Func<T, bool>? filter = null)
        where U : MyData<T>
    {
        var data = U.EnumerateData(path);
        if (filter != null) {
            data = data.Where(filter);
        }
        return data.Select(d => (U)U.Create(d)).ToList();
    }
}
```

I was struggling with a strange error in the `Select` method until I found that the solution was to cast the `MyData<T>` created by `U.Create(d)` to `U`:

> Error  CS8920  The interface 'MyProject.MyData' cannot be used as type argument. Static member 'MyProject.MyData.EnumerateData(string)' does not have a most specific implementation in the interface.

Possible usage:

```cs
List<MyFile> result =
    MyDataProcessing.GetData<FileInfo, MyFile>(@"C:\", f => f.Length > 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you! For your decision. I will definitely consider it.